# Python MySQL Statement output: 0 or 1

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to get Information from my database, and print it, but unfortunately, Instead of Printing the Information from the Table, it just Prints 0 or 1.

Why does it do this?
Can someone please help me?

```
sql = ("SELECT code FROM testing WHERE email = ((%s))")
sql2 = a.execute(sql, (fullemail))
sqlusername = ("SELECT username FROM testing123 WHERE code = ((%s))")
username = a.execute(sqlusername, (sql2))

print("Test3")
print(username)
```

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `execute()` method just returns the number of impacted rows.

You must use `.fetchall()` or equivalent (e.g. `.fetchone()`...) DBAPI methods to get a resultset.

Also, using parentheses alone around a single value: `(fullemail)` will not be recognized as a tuple, you need to explicitly add a comma so Python will recognize this as a tuple: `(fullemail, )`

```
sql = ("SELECT code FROM testing WHERE email = %s")
a.execute(sql, (fullemail, ))
sql2 = a.fetchall()

print(sql2)

sqlusername = ("SELECT username FROM testing123 WHERE code = %s")
a.execute(sqlusername, (sql2[0][0], ))
username = a.fetchall()

print("Test3")
print(username)
```

Depending on which library you are using:

- [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) (python 2.7)
- [mysqlclient](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/) (MySQLdb for python3)
- [PyMySQL](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (pure Python)

You can also use a `DictCursor` to get your result set rows as `dict` instead of `list`. Usage is like:

```
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect(host="", user="", passwd="", cursorclass=DictCursor)

with db.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SELECT ...")
    results = cur.fetchall()
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries instead of a list of lists.

Comment: I see you adjusted OP's setup with using actual one-item tuples. Consider mentioning this often mistake of new users. Even point OP and future readers to pymysql's [cursor objects docs](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html).